# Return row ID based on value in two other columns with mysql.connection

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have a list of username and passwords from one database #1 and I want to compare it to a list of usernames and passwords in DB #2.

If DB#2 has a username and password that is not in DB #1, it should be deleted.

So when iterating through the list and there is a match (meaning, DB#2 has a row that it should not in DB#1). How can I retrieve the row ID in DB#2 that corresponds to the entry?

When creating the two lists, i excluded the row ID since that would cause all entries to not match DB #1. So I filtered by only username and password columns.

Answer (score 0):

We can try using an `EXISTS` clause here along with `DELETE`:

```
DELETE
FROM table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1
                  WHERE t1.username = t2.username AND t1.password = t2.password);
```

If you want to first check to see which records in the second table do not have matching credentials in the first table, then we can use select with similar logic:

```
SELECT username, password
FROM table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1
                  WHERE t1.username = t2.username AND t1.password = t2.password);
```